# Why does $-x = -y \iff x = y?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

I was recently doing some work solving a trinomial by completing the square and found that towards the end I had four cases:

$$x = y$$
$$x = -y$$
$$-x = y$$
$$-x = -y$$

When I did the calculations it appeared that:
$$x = y \iff -x = -y$$
$$-x = y \iff x = -y$$

For what it’s worth, the initial equation was:
$$x^2 + 4x + 1 = 0$$
So that the solutions was: $\pm(x+2)=\pm\sqrt3$
and the cases enumerated as this list were:
$$x = \sqrt3 -2 $$
$$x = - \sqrt3 - 2$$
$$x = - \sqrt3 - 2 $$
$$x = \sqrt3 - 2$$

Had I of recognised this from the beginning I would have saved myself some work calculating the results (in fact, I did have an intuition this would be the case but I did the work anyway in case the intuition was false).

The explanation seems to be along the lines that anything multiplied by one is its self and anything you do to one side of the equation you must do to the other.  But I’m having difficulty formulating the proof that $$-x = -y \iff x = y$$

Comment: $-1$ is invertible... you can divide by it

Comment: or, $-x=-y$ and $0=0,\,x-x=y-y$ implies $x=y$

Comment: What does $==$ mean?

Comment: @MarkSaving I think it means "if and only if".

Comment: @MarkSaving I’m using it to mean ‘is equivalent to’.  Using another “ = “ symbol may have confused things more… let me know if there is some other symbol that would be more appropriate.

Comment: @duckegg I would suggest `\iff`, or if you want an (ironically) shorter arrow, go with `\Leftrightarrow`.

Comment: Using == is a bad idea. Writing "iff" would be better, or since you are already using MathJax `\iff` which renders to $\iff$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the substitution property of equality, we see that if $x = y$, then $-x = -y$.

For the converse, note that for all $z$, $--z = z$. So in particular, by the above, if $-x = -y$, then $--x = --y$. Then we have $x = --x = --y = y$.